# 年中 but for 週 - throughout the week

Tags: grammar, words

How do you say throughout the week?

> 日曜日は食べ物を作る。
> 週中は作った食べ物を一人で食べる。

Should I use 一週間 instead in place of 週中？ Maybe 次の週(間)？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

週中 is not common and 次の週 is a bit vague (次の週間 is not idiomatic).

一週間 works as you intend. Another possibility would be 平日(の間), which technically exclude Saturday though.

More commonly the situation would be described as

- 日曜日は一週間分の作り置きをする.

作り置き refers literally to 'cooked stock'.

---

Using 料理 would be more idiomatic than 食べ物 here.